# Choosing a single row based on multiple criteria

Tags: r, lag, ranking, lead

Can anyone think how to how to do this in R?

**Simple data:**

```
    seq<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B")
    rank<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4)
    match<-c("y","n","y","n","n","y","y")
    df<- as.data.frame(cbind(seq,rank,match))

      seq rank match
    1   A    1     y
    2   A    2     n
    3   A    3     y
    4   B    1     n
    5   B    2     n
    6   B    3     y
    7   B    4     y
```

I want to create a `‘choose’` column whereby, for every unique seq, the first instance of `y` under `match` is given a `T`, and all the rest are given a `F`.

The desired output would be:

```
      seq rank match choose
    1   A    1     y      T
    2   A    2     n      F
    3   A    3     y      F
    4   B    1     n      F
    5   B    2     n      F
    6   B    3     y      T
    7   B    4     y      F
```

It’s easy enough to return the correct value for rank 1 and 2 by combining an `ifelse` statement with lag, however I'm stumped once rank `>2`.

The real `dataset` contains`+100k rows`, and rank could go up to the hundreds, so I don’t want to just extend an `ifelse` statement to check values above using lag.

My ultimate aim is to create a new `dataset` from all of the T's under "choose", so if someone know how to directly pull them out without creating a new column that would be even better!

I’m guessing an `ifelse` statement is a daft way of doing this, but I’m stuck :/

Any help would be much appreciated : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(seq) %>%
 mutate(choose = +(match == "y") * (cumsum(match == "y") == 1))

  seq   rank  match choose
  <fct> <fct> <fct>  <int>
1 A     1     y          1
2 A     2     n          0
3 A     3     y          0
4 B     1     n          0
5 B     2     n          0
6 B     3     y          1
7 B     4     y          0
```

And if you want to have TRUE/FALSE values:

```
df %>%
 group_by(seq) %>%
 mutate(choose = as.logical(+(match == "y") * (cumsum(match == "y") == 1)))

  seq   rank  match choose
  <fct> <fct> <fct> <lgl> 
1 A     1     y     TRUE  
2 A     2     n     FALSE 
3 A     3     y     FALSE 
4 B     1     n     FALSE 
5 B     2     n     FALSE 
6 B     3     y     TRUE  
7 B     4     y     FALSE
```

And the same with `base R`:

```
with(df, ave(match, seq, FUN = function(x) +(x == "y") * (cumsum(x == "y") == 1)))
```

Or:

```
with(df, ave(match, seq, FUN = function(x) as.logical(+(x == "y") * (cumsum(x == "y") == 1))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And thank you to the others for your answers too (stackoverflow won't allow me to @ more than one person). You’re all very generous to take time out of your day to help a total stranger. Also, I _must_ get to grips with dplyr! It seems to be the answer to most things :/

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(seq) %>% filter(choose =="T") %>% top_n(1) %>% mutate(choose = "T")

df[is.na(df)] <- "F
```

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
df %>%
  group_by(seq) %>%
  mutate(choose = row_number() %in% which(match == 'y')[1])
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   seq [2]
  seq   rank  match choose
  <fct> <fct> <fct> <lgl> 
1 A     1     y     TRUE  
2 A     2     n     FALSE 
3 A     3     y     FALSE 
4 B     1     n     FALSE 
5 B     2     n     FALSE 
6 B     3     y     TRUE  
7 B     4     y     FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the new column as a logical vector which is `TRUE` when `match == 'y'` and the row is the first occurrence of the (match, seq) pair (i.e. `rowid(match, seq) == 1`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, choose := match == 'y' & rowid(match, seq) == 1]

df
#    seq rank match choose
# 1:   A    1     y   TRUE
# 2:   A    2     n  FALSE
# 3:   A    3     y  FALSE
# 4:   B    1     n  FALSE
# 5:   B    2     n  FALSE
# 6:   B    3     y   TRUE
# 7:   B    4     y  FALSE
```

Or to directly subset the data without creating a new column

```
df[match == 'y' & rowid(match, seq) == 1]

#    seq rank match
# 1:   A    1     y
# 2:   B    3     y
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(seq) %>% 
   mutate(choose = row_number() == match("y", match))
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   seq [2]
#  seq   rank  match choose
#  <fct> <fct> <fct> <lgl>                              
#1 A     1     y     TRUE                               
#2 A     2     n     FALSE                              
#3 A     3     y     FALSE                              
#4 B     1     n     FALSE                              
#5 B     2     n     FALSE                              
#6 B     3     y     TRUE                               
#7 B     4     y     FALSE
```